# By clicking a button send to another react native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I was trying via React Native to get the Get Started button to take me to the Home component with the name Wallet but if I click on the button nothing happens, how can I solve this by sending to the component from the click of the button

Via the button send to the Home component where the wallet starts but currently the button is not clickable.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from "../Home/Home";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const GetStartedBtn = ({ title }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        width: 327,
        paddingVertical: 14,
        paddingHorizontal: 115,
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        gap: 10,
        borderRadius: 16,
        backgroundColor: "#6552FE",
        marginTop: 40,
        marginLeft: 20,
      }}
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate("Wallet");
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontFamily: "SFProText-Semibold" }}>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

export default function Start() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Wallet" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

      <View>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/logo/logo2.png")}
            alt="Logo"
            style={{
              width: 400,
              height: 400,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              marginTop: -110,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/img/start/startimage.png")}
            alt=""
            style={{
              width: 400,
              height: 400,
              flexShrink: 0,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              marginTop: -100,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            fontFamily: "SFProText-Semibold",
            fontSize: 32,
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontWeight: 500,
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginTop: -30,
            width: 300,
          }}
        >
          Jump start your crypto portfolio
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            fontFamily: "SFProText-Light",
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginTop: 20,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontStyle: "normal",
          }}
        >
          Take your investment portfolio to the next level
        </Text>
        <View>
          <GetStartedBtn title="Get Started" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have another screen where includes startup button in the stack navigator.

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Image, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from "../Home/Home";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const GetStartedBtn = ({ title }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        width: 327,
        paddingVertical: 14,
        paddingHorizontal: 115,
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        gap: 10,
        borderRadius: 16,
        backgroundColor: "#6552FE",
        marginTop: 40,
        marginLeft: 20,
      }}
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate("Wallet");
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontFamily: "SFProText-Semibold" }}>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

function Splash() {
 return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/logo/logo2.png")}
            alt="Logo"
            style={{
              width: 400,
              height: 400,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              marginTop: -110,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/img/start/startimage.png")}
            alt=""
            style={{
              width: 400,
              height: 400,
              flexShrink: 0,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              marginTop: -100,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            fontFamily: "SFProText-Semibold",
            fontSize: 32,
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontWeight: 500,
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginTop: -30,
            width: 300,
          }}
        >
          Jump start your crypto portfolio
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            fontFamily: "SFProText-Light",
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginTop: 20,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontStyle: "normal",
          }}
        >
          Take your investment portfolio to the next level
        </Text>
        <View>
          <GetStartedBtn title="Get Started" />
        </View>
      </View>
 )
}
export default function Start() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Wallet" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```